# How do I get a the pending status to automatically show up?

Tags: php, html, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have this leave form where employees can apply for a leave. Everything works fine, the only problem is I can't get the pending status to show up. I've already defined the default value of `status` on my table.

Here's what it looks like when I view the leaves:

[view-leave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuINJ.png)

and here's my table structure:

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kpqG.png)

I'm not sure if you guys need my view-leave code but here it is:

```js
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
 <tr>
  <th>Employee Name</th>
  <th>Phone</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>From</th>
  <th>To</th>
  <th>Reason</th>
  <th>Status</th>
 </tr>
<?php
 include ('database.php');
 $result = $database->prepare ("SELECT * FROM leaves order by id DESC");
 $result ->execute();
 for ($count=0; $row_message = $result ->fetch(); $count++){
?>
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $row_message['full_name']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row_message['phone']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row_message['email']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row_message['fromdate']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row_message['todate']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row_message['reason']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row_message['status']; ?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php } ?>
</table>

<a href="home"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i> Back</button></a>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't include links to table structures, etc.  Please actually paste them in to the question.

Comment: @MatBailie Like paste the picture? I think you can only do that with 10+ rep.

Comment: It appears that you inserted the data and ***then*** applied the default?
  ***Or*** you specifically inserted a `NULL` or empty string?  The default only get's used during an `INSERT` ***and*** when you don't supply a value.  For example, if a table has fields `a, b, c` and `c` has a default, you could use : `INSERT INTO table (a, b) VALUES (1, 2)`.  If you give `c` a value, be it `NULL` or an empty string, the default won't be applied.  It certainly isn't applied during a `SELECT`.  This means that you'll have to `UPDATE` those rows.

Comment: You should rarely use images anyway.  Use text.

Comment: try another insert leaving status field empty

Comment: @jpec - It's not a matter of leaving it empty, it's specifically saying you're inserting into columns `a, b` but NOT mentioning column `c` ; `INSERT INTO table (a, b) VALUES (1, 2)`.  If you don't enumerate the columns, you're telling the database you're populating ***all*** the columns, this means this syntax will ***never*** populate a default ; `INSERT INTO table VALUES` *(you **must** include the column list, and you **must** exclude from that list the column to apply the default to)*.

Comment: @MatBailie Does this mean I should set `status` to not null? and what do you mean by updating the rows?

Comment: I assumed he'd done the insert before applying the default value to the column, also we don't have a reference to the qry

Answer (score 0):

The `DEFAULT` key word determines behaviour during an `INSERT`, not during a `SELECT`.  Whatever values are in the table are what you will see, regardless of what the current `DEFAULT` is.

If you want something similar to a default during a `SELECT`, try the following...

```
SELECT
    id,
    full_name,
    phone,
    email,
    fromdate,
    todate,
    reason,
    COALESCE(status, 'Pending')   AS status
FROM
    leaves
ORDER BY
     id DESC
```

This will replace all `NULL` values in `status` with `'Pending'` while you are selecting the data. It won't change anything in the table, just in your results.

If you want to change what is in the table to get rid of those "blank" values, the you need to do an `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE
    leaves
SET
    status = 'Pending'
WHERE
       status IS NULL
    OR status = ''
```

If you want to stop blanks values getting in to the table in the future, you need to specifically mention all the fields ***except*** for the the ones that you want to have a default applied.

```
INSERT INTO
    leaves (
        full_name,
        phone,
        email,
        fromdate,
        todate,
        reason
    )
VALUES (
    'Joe Bloggs',
    '555 555 555',
    'joe@bloggs.com',
    '2017-04-01',
    '2018-12-25',
    'Just Because'
)
```

That list of field names at the start is critical.

If you skip it, you're telling the database you want to set the values for ***every*** column, and so you never want the default used.  The same is true if you include `status` in the list : Even if you give the value `NULL` or `''`, you're telling the database that's the value you want, regardless of what the default might be.